# Angular: interpolate string Kendo CellClickEvent in other component

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui

For my application, I have three components:

- Component A: Couples component B and C
- Component B: A grid containing objects
- Component C: A form showing details when a row in the grid of component B is clicked

> ```
> +---------------------+
> |  A                  | 
> | +------+  +-------+ |
> | |  B   |  |  C    | |
> | |      |  |       | |
> | +------+  +-------+ |
> +---------------------+
> ```

```
export class B{

   @Output() rowClicked= new EventEmitter<{objectOfInterest: any}>();

   public onCellClick (e){
     this.rowClicked.emit(e.dataItem);
   }
}
```

And the KendoUI grid has bound the event like this:
`(cellClick)="onCellClick($event)"`. The event gets called correctly and contains the dataItem of the row that was clicked.

In the template of component A, I use the following selector:

`<B (rowClicked)='C.doStuff($event)'></B>`

Then, class C comes along:

```
export class C{
  public objectOfInterest: any = {};

  constructor(){
    this.objectOfInterest= {'name': 'blaat'};
  }

  public doStuff = (objOfInterest) => {
    this.objectOfInterest= objOfInterest;
    console.log(this.objectOfInterest.name);
  }
}
```

Also, the console.log prints the correct string (the name of the entity which was clicked).

Now the issue: The template of C contains a string interpolation which looks like this: `Editting {{objectOfInterest.name}}`. No matter what I do, the name of the clicked object is not printed to the screen. Also tried:

`Editting {{objectOfInterest?.name}}`

or

`<div *ngIf="someBool">{{objectOfInterest.name}}</div>`

all to no satisfying result.

I keep thinking I'm in the wrong context of `this` but when I'm in `doStuff` and I do `console.log(this)` it outputs the expected stuff: the objectOfInterest and the doStuff method.

Comment: Why don't you write your function normally, e.g. `doStuff(objectOfInterest) {...}`  ? Is there a particular reason not to ?

Comment: @trichetriche: I started out with 'normal' functions, but I started suspecting the context of `this` was going haywire, so I converted doStuff to the class method notation `dostuff = () => {}`

Comment: Well I would rather go for a change detection issue, before a context one. Did you try using the change detector in your C component ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scenario seems to work here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/5Mp4lDuthIJ0SgUEhG2q?p=preview

This will not work if you are using OnPush change detection strategy. In this case you should use the C component [ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#markforcheck) method or use Input instead of method and perform any additional logic in the setter:

```
export class C{

  public objectOfInterest: any = {};

  @Input()
  public set objOfInterest(value: any) {
    this.objectOfInterest = value;
    //do stuff
  }

}

<B (rowClicked)='objectOfInterest = $event.dataItem'></B>

<C [objOfInterest]="objectOfInterest"></C>
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out it was the template reference that was missing;
`<b #b></b>` which I didn't know the existence of.